# How to create a c# char array from given address value and size

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

In my project, I'm using a function of a c# wrapper which wraps a c++ dll. The function has as parameters the address value and size of the char array referenced by the wrapped c++ function.
How can I create the char array from these elements in my c# project?

*c++ function*

```
/*
* this function creates a char array
* addressRes --> addres of the first element of the created char array
* sizeRes --> size of the created char array
*/
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned Cpp_function(unsigned * addressRes, unsigned * sizeRes);
```

*c# wrapper function*

```
[DllImport("mycpp.dll", EntryPoint = "Cpp_function", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern uint _Cpp_function(ref uint addressRes, ref uint sizeRes);
public override uint CS_function(ref uint addressRes, ref uint sizeRes)
{
    return _Cpp_function(ref addressRes, ref sizeRes);
}
```

*my c# function*

```
public void MyFunc()
{
    uint address = 0;
    uint size = 0;
    char[] res;
    MyWrapper myWrapper = new MyWrapper();
    
    myWrapper.CS_function(ref address, ref size);
    
    // create a char array from address and size
}
```

Comment: Great, you've shared what you've tried! What did you expect to happen? What *is* happening (odd behaviour, exception message, stack trace, compiler error message?

Comment: `char` like a C++ char (8 bit usually) or a C# char (16 bit UTF16 code point)? You can have a look at [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringansi) or [Marshal.PtrToStringUni](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringuni)

Comment: And: `usigned int` will not be wide enough to represent an address in a 64 bit process

Comment: @Luke everything works well. No excpetion is thrown

Comment: The fact is no exceptions have happened yet. You should not forget to pin your memory before passing it on to C++ (or the garbage collector may move the memory around invalidating your C++ pointers). In general I better like to work the other way around. Create a mangaged C++/CLI project do all my memory managment (pinning) in that wrapper (or return copies under .Net lifetime control). This might give you some ideas : [Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes)